# Telerik DragDrop Does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, telerik

I've been developing a software and i want to use telerik `Listbox` drag&drag. 
the problem is when i drop an item from one listbox to another it does not work at all.

It seems that the drop event does not fire.

1. I set `allowdrop= true`
2. I added `dragvisualprovider`
3. I set `allowreorder = true`

I also tried to write code when `dragLeave` and `PreDrop` Events Fire and add that item into the new `Listbox`. but it works sometimes correct by chance!!!

*I don't use MVVM Model*

4. based on what telerik site says, I don't use static items collection. I create new items in my page load and add it to first `Listbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `<telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior AllowReorder="True" />` like this:

```
<telerik:RadListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, ElementName=editor,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DraggableListBoxItem}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" ItemsSource="{Binding LeaveActions,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" AllowDrop="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
        <telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior AllowReorder="True" />
    </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

Than every thing should work well. If you want to get into the drag/drop events, just use the telerik `DragDropmanager`.